# setFilter tooltip is not showing in filter list ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I am using ag-grid 22.1.1 version in that in filter list i am not able to see tooltips I have set property

```
filterParams:{showTooltips:true}` in specific column fields.
```

Here is like ag-grid doc https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/filter-set-filter-list/#filter-value-tooltips

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1):

The Set Filter tooltip is a feature that was released in v23.1.0 as documented in the changelog:

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/

> AG-588    Feature Request 23.1.0  Add tooltip to Set Filter List

I would recommend upgrading to the latest version, or at least v23.1.0.

Comment: Ahh Thanks @Shuheb Ahmed